# Sklearn FeatureUnion returns TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('int64'), dtype('O'))

Tags: python, types, scikit-learn

I am trying to unite two pipelines:

- *pipeline_1* returns a sparse matrix of float64
- *pipeline_2* returns the original column (str) in the form of a pandas DataFrame (a Series wouldn't lead to an error *ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions.* )

While doing that, I receive the error:

*TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('int64'), dtype('O'))*

My goal is to find a generalized way to keep the original column of the DataFrame in the pipeline to be used by classifiers later on.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion


class ColumnSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, key, transform_function=None):
        self.key = key
        self.transform_function = transform_function

    def fit(self, X, y=None, *parg, **kwarg):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        result = X[self.key]
        if self.transform_function:
            result = self.transform_function(result)
        return result


data = [
    {'col1': 'hello my friend', 'col2': 'somestring_'},
    {'col1': 'my friend', 'col2': 'somestring__'},
    {'col1': 'hello friend', 'col2': 'somestring___'}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)



pipeline_1 = Pipeline([
    ('selector', ColumnSelector(key='col1')),
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer())
])

pipeline_2 = Pipeline([
    ('test', ColumnSelector(key='col2'))#, transform_function=lambda col: col.to_frame())),
])

feats = FeatureUnion([('count_vectorize', pipeline_1), ('original_column', pipeline_2)])

feats.fit_transform(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

FeatureUnion uses numpy or scipy sparse operation to join the output of each features in it. Hence, you cannot have any step in the FeatureUnion that can return non numerical values.

If I change your `pipeline2` to return the number of characters in the given string, it will start working.

Note: you can use `ColumnTransformer` from `sklearn.compose`.

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion


class ColumnSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, key, transform_function=None):
        self.key = key
        self.transform_function = transform_function

    def fit(self, X, y=None, *parg, **kwarg):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        result = X[self.key]
        if self.transform_function:
            result = self.transform_function(result)
        return result


data = [
    {'col1': 'hello my friend', 'col2': 'somestring_'},
    {'col1': 'my friend', 'col2': 'somestring__'},
    {'col1': 'hello friend', 'col2': 'somestring___'}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)



pipeline_1 = Pipeline([
    ('selector', ColumnSelector(key='col1')),
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer())
])

pipeline_2 = Pipeline([
    ('test', ColumnSelector(key='col2',transform_function=lambda x: [[len(i)] for i in x]))#, transform_function=lambda col: col.to_frame())),
])

feats = FeatureUnion([('count_vectorize', pipeline_1), ('original_column', pipeline_2)])

feats.fit_transform(df)
```